# MAX() slow query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, query-optimization

I have this query to fetch most recent conversations grouped by phone number, however the query time is too slow. How can it be faster?

```
SELECT * from messages WHERE id IN (SELECT max(id) from messages GROUP BY phone) AND chat = :ch AND status = :st AND seller_id = :seller ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

DB Version 10.2.44-MariaDB

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing any specifics of the database. What are the indexes on the `messages` table and how many records are in the table?

Comment: approximately 600,000 records.

Comment: Thanks for the record count, it eliminated possibilities. Assuming you can make changes to the database (and speaking generally): if the `id` column doesn't have an index on it, one should be added; you can also change the query into a stored procedure. Both of these should speed up the query. Since you haven't specified what "slow" is I've answered in a general way. A big speed factor with databases is they system/machine they are running on. Making sure your machine is powerful enough for the database is important

Comment: The EXPLAIN feature might also help you optimize: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/sql-explain.html

Comment: Include `SHOW CREATE TABLE messages` because answering only one of the questions wasn't  enough. [window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions/) instead of the subquery might help. MariaDB has [EXPLAIN](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain-format-json/) too.

Comment: thanks @ChrisSc, i created an index for 'phone' and the time reduced considerably.

Comment: That's great news! I will make that the answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main ways to speed up a query is to add an index to the column(s) involved. Adding an index to the `id` column will speed up the query (if there isn't an index on it already).

As @danblack mentions in the comments, MariaDB has an EXPLAIN feature that will analyze a query. The analysis can then be used to optimize the query.

There also are more sophisticated techniques for speeding up a query, such as writing a stored procedure, if the above doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This will significantly speed up the subquery:

```
INDEX(phone)
```

I assume you already have `PRIMARY KEY(id).

This reformulation *may* improve the query plan:

```
SELECT messages.*
    FROM ( SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM messages GROUP BY phone ) AS x
    JOIN messages  ON messages.id = x.maxid
    WHERE  chat = :ch
      AND  status = :st
      AND  seller_id = :seller
    ORDER BY  created_at DESC
```

A stored procedure will not help enough to warrant its usage.

`EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` should always be included when asking performance questions.